# React Profiler: "Timeline profiling not supported"?

Tags: reactjs

I'm debugging my React app on Mac using Chrome. I've installed React 18, and the latest React Devtools Chrome extension:

[image]

When I go to the React Profiler tab and click the record button, I see:

> Timeline profiling not supported. Timeline profiler requires a
> development or profiling build of react-dom@^18.
>
> Click here to learn more about profiling.

Okay, so I go to [the React docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/Profiler#caveats) and it talks about adding a `<Profiler>` component. I did that and still get the same error.

What am I missing?

**Update:**

In response to comments, I found out how to show whether React is running in dev or production mode. Here's a screen shot of a dialog provided by React Dev Tools. (Click on the React Dev Tools icon to see it).

[image]

**Update #2:**

A commenter asked how I was including React in my project. Here's the complete code I'm using for this:

```
import React from 'react'
import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client';
import {App} from '../../client/ui/router'
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";


function onRender(
    id, // the "id" prop of the Profiler tree that has just committed
    phase, // either "mount" (if the tree just mounted) or "update" (if it re-rendered)
    actualDuration, // time spent rendering the committed update
    baseDuration, // estimated time to render the entire subtree without memoization
    startTime, // when React began rendering this update
    commitTime, // when React committed this update
    interactions // the Set of interactions belonging to this update
) {
    // Aggregate or log render timings...
    console.log({
        id,
        phase,
        actualDuration,
        baseDuration,
        startTime,
        commitTime,
        interactions
    });
}


const container = document.getElementById('app');
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <React.Profiler id="App" onRender={onRender}>
            <App />
        </React.Profiler>
    </BrowserRouter>
)
```

Comment: I  think we need more info about how you're using react in your code and how you're running you app.  You installed react 18. but are you actually using it?  Are you runnning in dev mode or a build?  We need a bit more context

Comment: Great question! Yes, I am definitely using React. My UI is built with the mui react components and they are definitely working. :) On my dev system I **guess** I'm running in dev mode --- how would I check that? I've googled a lot for info about how to check that and haven't yet found the answer. My build tool is Meteor. I'll ask on the Meteor forums about this too.

Comment: Okay I'm definitely running React in development mode. I've updated the original post with a screenshot. So.... why isn't React profiler cooperating?

Comment: How are you including react in your project?  `import React from 'react'`?  From a CDN?

Comment: In response to @SethLutske's comment, I've updated the original post with the code I'm using to include react.